# Knowing which derived class a base class pointer points to

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived-class

Suppose I have an Animal class and two classes - Dog and Cat derive from it.
It is perfectly legal to do this -

```
Dog d;
Cat c;
Animal* a1 = &c;
Animal* a2 = &d;
```

Now, given a1 and a2, can I know which derived class this pointer points to?

The only idea I have right now is to add one more member field inside Animal class and initializing it in constructors. Is this even a good practice?

Comment: No, it is not good practice. It is usually a sign that there is more thinking left to do.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is legal, and yes that is one way of going back to the original type. You can also use dynamic_cast, but that has overhead. Generally the program stores it in the derived type and only refers to it with the base class when it doesn't matter.

I find if you are having to do something like dynamic_cast you have to reconsider the design of your program.

Answer (score 1):

you can use dynamic_cast to find out. Dynamic_cast uses run-time type check and will fail if it cannot convert accordingly.

```
ex: Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base)
```

Also if you use VStudio, you can use 
`typeid(*a1).name.` That'd give you the class name pointed to by a1 pointer.

Comment: typeid isn't purely a Visual Studio thing.

Comment: Isn't it assuming that I know type of base pointer?
In my question, will I write
`Cat* ptr = dynamic_cast<Cat*>a1` or 
`Dog* ptr = dynamic_cast<Dog*>a1`?

Comment: yes. But since dynamic_cast is safe cast (checks run-time type information to ensure a meaningful conversion can happen), you'd either get a valid pointer to requested type or null. If you don't know the object pointed to, then use typeid(*a1).name="Cat" , typeid(*a1) == "dog"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dominic. I just like add two points here that the `dynamic_cast` overhead varies from compiler to compiler and if you don't have the option of re-designing your program then you have no options left,but to use `dynamic_cast`.(In case(not your case in question) where you are sure of the type then always prefer to use `static_cast`, it has very less overhead.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10315029)

Comment: @Bartłomiej Semańczyk...the answer is to use dynamic_cast as suggested by others.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a field.

As others have mentioned, `dynamic_cast<T>()` can be used but you need to be careful and know when it will work and when not. For it to work you need RTTI (run-time type information) which is not always present/valid (such as when using libraries etc.)

I agree with @Dominic McDonnell:

> I find if you are having to do something like dynamic_cast you have to reconsider the design of your program.

PS: *If you are using Qt then you can use `qobject_cast<T>()` since Qt adds this type of information to `QObject` type objects without the need for RTTI*