C++ best way to compare between 2 class instances inherited from same base class
i have 2 classs
class State : public godot::Node
    {
         

    public:
        State();
        virtual ~State() = default;
        virtual void _physics_process(double delta) override;
        virtual void enter();
        virtual void exit();
        virtual void update(double delta);
        virtual void _ready() override;


    protected:
        static void _bind_methods();
        Player* player;
    private:
        



    };


class WalkingPlayerState : public State {
         

    public:
        WalkingPlayerState() {
        };
        virtual ~WalkingPlayerState() = default;
        void update(double delta);
        

    protected:
        static void _bind_methods() {};
    private:
    
}


class IdlePlayerState: public State {
         

    public:
        IdlePlayerState() {};
        virtual ~IdlePlayerState() = default;
         
        void update(double delta);
     
        
    protected:
        static void _bind_methods() {};
    private:
}

Okay, so somewhere in the code, I'd like to compare between WalkingPlayerState and IdlePlayerState. I mean to check if a pointer is of type WalkingPlayerState or IdlePlayerState.
Imagine i have Dictionary that holes all the states
State* state =  stateNodes[i];

and now i like to check if
state == WalkingPlayerState or IdlePlayerState 

Now I'd like to check if state is equal to WalkingPlayerState or IdlePlayerState. How can this be done in C++? Do I need to include a string/enum member in each class, or is there a better way to do it without adding extra members?

One question is "Why do you want to do this?" Why are you checking the exact type of the pointer? You've got a base class State with a bunch of virtual methods. If the different derived classes need to do different things, are their different implementations of the virtual methods not sufficient? If you really need to actually check the type itself, there's dynamic_cast.

std::is_same?

@Dúthomhas looks like it compares Type not pointers or instances

AFAIK The only way to get the actual type the pointer points to is to try casting and seeing if the cast succeeds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33886534/4342498

typeid I think will also use RTTI and that would be one other way

Confirmed about typeid, link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138770/get-objects-type-from-pointer-to-base-class-at-runtime

you want to use dynamic_cast, the typeid way will only work for the most derived type, it doesn't check the inherence hierarchy , if you use typeid then you have to mark them final to tell people they cannot inherit from it and expect the code to work, the typeid operator is faster, (about as fast as using an enum).

if RTTI is disabled in your project https://llvm.org/docs/HowToSetUpLLVMStyleRTTI.html

Try this:  class State { public: virtual  bool isWalkingState() const {return false;} }

For runtime checks, you could use dynamic cast, which tries to cast from the input type, to the given template type, and returns either a pointer of the type that's templated, or nullptr if it failed to cast... and a simple if statement will automatically treat that as true/false...
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base(){};
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Derived1(){};
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Derived2(){};
};

int main()
{
    // Create derived object
    Derived1 object;
    // Get base pointer from derived object
    Base* object_ptr = &object;

    // Check if base object pointer is either of the two derived types
    if (dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(object_ptr) || dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(object_ptr))
    {
        std::cout << "Pointer is one of those!" << std::endl;
    }
}

Though, you have to ask yourself if you need to do this. As you are already using polymorphism, then most situations can be solved with virtual methods. If a situation can't be solved that way for a  ploymorphic heirachy, then maybe one or more of these derived classes shouldn't be a derived object.
If you need the pointer itself from the cast, then you can do the following, although in my books this is even more of a hint that your class heirachy might need a rethink:
int main()
{
    // Create derived object
    Derived2 object;
    // Get base pointer from derived object
    Base* object_ptr = &object;

    // Check if base object pointer is either of the two derived types
    if (Derived2* derived_ptr = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(object_ptr))
    {
        derived_ptr->do_struff();
    }
}

There are also type traits available for runtime type checks and template specialisations. If that sounds useful, I'd look at concepts like std::same_as and type traits like sts::is_same std::is_base_of.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of

Here are some ideas:
class State
{
  public:
    virtual bool isWalkingState() const
      { return false;}
};
class WalkingPlayerState : public State
{
  public:
    bool isWalkingState() const
      { return true;}
};

Or you could use an enum:
class State
{
  public:
    enum State_Type { UNKNOWN_STATE = 0; STATE_WALKING, STATE_IDLE};
    virtual State_Type getState() const
    { return UNKNOWN_STATE;}
};
class WalkingPlayerState : public State
{
  public:
     State::State_Type getState() const
     { return State::State_Type::STATE_WALKING; }
};

The primary idea is to use an interface in the base State class that returns the type or state ID.  The base class implements a default interface and the children implement the actual values.
